# Is this sentence correct "If did not do my homework I would have to do my home work tomorrow"?

Tags: grammar

Currently I am doing my home work. And I just want to know the sentence which is given bellow can fit in this context.
"If I did not do my homework I would have to do my home work tomorrow?"
If it does not fit in the context then what will be the correct sentence?

Comment: I'd rather revise it in a couple of ways; if you intend to emphasize the specific time that you didn't do your homework, say yesterday, then "If I didn't do the homework YESTERDAY, I'd have to do it tomorrow". if it's not and you want to emphasize the 'state' of your homework not having done until now, then "If I haven't done (with) my homework, I'd have to do it (by) tomorrow".

Comment: Actually I realized the former one is a little bit awkward, as someone not having done with his/her own homework seems not likely to be an assumption.

Comment: Is your latter one a Conditional Sentences Type II?

Comment: Well actually I never knew the conditional sentences have types :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to first tell what you actually want to express, and then we can say whether a sentence expresses this and/or whether it is correct English.

If you say "If I didn't do my homework" without any qualification, I would interpret it as "If I never did homework". In that case you would obviously not do your homework today, tomorrow, or any day.

If you were given homework today that is due the day after tomorrow, then you would say "If I didn't do my homework today, I would have to do it tomorrow". You would probably say "it" instead of repeating "my homework".

If your teacher or lecturer told you that you had to do either today's or tomorrow's homework, but not both, you would say "If I didn't do my homework today, I would have to do tomorrow's homework".

If your teacher / lecturer gets angry if you don't do your homework, but gets *very* angry if you don't do homework twice in a row, you would say "If I didn't do my homework today, I would *really* have to do tomorrow's homework".

Comment: "If I didn't do... I would have to" is incongruent here.  There are three possible states and each of them has a better phrasing.  Homework is already done, consideration of counter-factual: "*If I hadn't done... I would have to*".  Homework is not yet done, but is planned, consideration of unlikely possibility: "*If I don't do... I will have to*".  And third, homework is neither done nor planned, contemplation of factual future: "*Because I am not doing... I will have to*".